# Laravel 10 Vue 3 Vuetify 3 Vite Application not running without npm run dev running

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js, vite

I have created an application with Laravel 10, Vue 3, Inertia Js, Vuetify 3...The problem is when the npm run dev running in the background everything works fine. After running npm run build command for production files are generating in public/build/assets folder but not working in the browser without npm run dev. First I installed laravel 10 vue 3 inertia with breeze then installed vuetify separately with npm commands and configuring the app.js. I tried many things but couldn't solve the issue. Some how static css files not using. I have used  `npm install vite-plugin-vuetify`
then in vite.config.js

`import vuetify from 'vite-plugin-vuetify';`
`vuetify({ autoImport: true }),`

Its not working as well :(

In the console showing,
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://[::1]:5173/resources/js/app.js. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://[::1]:5173/resources/js/Pages/Frontend.vue. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://[::1]:5173/@vite/client. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

I have used  `npm install vite-plugin-vuetify`
then in vite.config.js

`import vuetify from 'vite-plugin-vuetify';`
`vuetify({ autoImport: true }),`

Its not working as well :(